# android BroadcastReceiver doesn't get called

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-5.0-lollipop

I've seen a lot of question like this around and I've tried a bunch of things without success... 
I just want to log a sms received using a subclass of BroadcastReceiver like I've seen in so many tutorial...
so here is my code and config

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
package com.example.koki.mysms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "test");
        Toast.makeText(context, "ON RECEIVE BROADCAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

there's nothing in my **MainActivity** beside what you get when creating a new projet with android studio.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.koki.mysms" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the way I test it (not very familiar in android development yet), is that I have two emulator and I sent sms to one another. They both receive the sms but nothing in the logcat nor the Toast appear. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you run the app after installation, before you send the SMS? That is, do you open `MainActivity` at least once?

Comment: well, I don't know why but, after removing et re-instantiating some virtual devices, now it's working. I couldn't explain why. thanks anyways!!